# accessing worksheets other than worksheet 1 in google sheets api v4

Tags: google-sheets-api

Is there a way to access different worksheets with the new API.
eg. I have a spreadsheet called data and a worksheet called classes and swords. if I wanted to read A1:f7 on the swords worksheet (worksheet 2).

Used to be able to do it with v3 but unless I'm missing something does not look like you can read any other worksheet except worksheet 1 on a spreadsheet currently.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a values.get request using the A1 notation of the range you'd like, which includes the sheet name and range.  For example use: `swords!A1:F7`.

[A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation) is explained here.

Here's a [rough outline](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading_a_single_range) of how to read one range. Here's some [more detail](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading#read_a_single_range).  And here's the [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) for values.get.

Comment: Ah thanks, did not realise you could do it like that when i was reading it